# title property not working in ipad but works in desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, ios8

I have the code as

```
  <button aria-label="Export account balances as a PDF" title="PDF" class="button icon ui-widget-override" 
type="button" id="export-pdf-button" onclick="viewPdfAccountBal();">
    <img alt="PDF" title="PDF" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/pdf_icon.gif"/>
    </button>
```

this shows the word as "PDF" when I move the over the image icon, but I am unable to replicate that hover in ipad. I also should not affect the existing working code due to this change too.

Can you please help me in this since I am struggling for a couple of days

Comment: <button aria-label="Export account balances as a PDF" title="PDF11111" class="button icon ui-widget-override" type="button" id="export-pdf-button" onclick="viewPdfAccountBal();"><img alt="PDF" title="PDF1222" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/pdf_icon.gif"/></button>

Comment: How do you hover on an iPad??

Comment: Just by double tapping in ipad, i use chrome browsers mobile feature for development, where I hold on the image using mouse